# ZedGraph - PointPairList not work with AxisType is TEXT

Tags: zedgraph

I am hoping someone help me for this question.

I have a need to show chart by using ZedGraph like a demo here

http://zedgraph.dariowiz.com/index4df2-2.html?title=Scatter_Plot_Demo

**I want to use "XAxis.Type" is Text type because XAxis values are "string" value.** 
But it does not work correctly anymore with this code snippet

```
string[] labels = { "USA", "Spain\nMadrid", "Qatar", "Morocco", "UK", "Uganda",
                "Cambodia", "Malaysia", "Australia", "Ecuador" };    
myPane.XAxis.Type = ZedGraph.AxisType.Text;
myPane.XAxis.TextLabels = labels;
```

I have tried to find the answer by (reading documentation, google) but not successfully.